# Cannot open Insights -> Contributors, always loading

Tags: github

I just created my first repository today and pushed some codes on GitHub.

However, when I checked the contributors, it was always loading like this:
[image]

I am sure I pushed some code:
[image]

And even I log off it still won't help. I tried to view other people's repositories. Some of them can display the graphs. Some cannot, too.

Is it because I forgot to turn on something?

Comment: If other people's repos aren't working either (I just looked at [one of mine](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/graphs/contributors) and got the same loading spinner for a while) that tells you something's wrong at GitHub's end. You only have one contributor, so it won't show you anything interesting anyway!

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually I just want to see how many lines I have. XD

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I found this from github docs, I think my contribution will be shown today. xD

[image]